# ImageJ add watermark

Tags: watermark, imagej

ImageJ: What is the best way to add watermark to image?

I use two images the original image and the watermark image. The problem (in watermark image)is that I cannot change the opacity of the text without changing the opacity of the background. Note: the background transparency is 100% if I did not change opacity of the text

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use this tool: http://www.paintshoppro.com/en/pages/watermark-photos/ to add watermark to your photos, because sometimes watermarks can make your photos safer, but they can also be very easily removed, so your back to where you started. if you do it with that tool and make a transparent watermark, it wouldn't disturb the concept of the photo, but would also be much harder to remove.